# How Can I hide same value in the JTable by using DefaultTableCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I make a timetable with Java, but I cannot solve one problem.

I want to change the foreground color as same as background color or Hiding a value, when some cells have a same value at first detected cell.

Like this...

[image]

Here's what I made...

[image]

(Sorry about Korean words...)

So, I want to use a `DefaultTableCellRenderer`, but I can't find a good example about this.

And, I don't know how `DefaultTableCellRenderer` works. Can't find any explains about that...

So, I want to ask a favor about that problem.

Here's my code:

```
public class subject_table_renderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{ 
private Object subject_name = "";
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean   isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
{ 
    Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); 
    if (! isSelected) 
    {
        if(value.equals("")){
                cell.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        else{
            String[] temp = MainFrame.find_list((String)value, MainFrame.subject);
            //take a subject_list for decide background color

            if(!value.equals(subject_name)){
                subject_name = value;
                cell.setBackground(get_rand_color(cell, Integer.parseInt(temp[6])));
            }
            else{   
                cell.setBackground(get_rand_color(cell, Integer.parseInt(temp[6])));
                cell.setForeground(get_rand_color(cell, Integer.parseInt(temp[6])));
            }
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: `subject_table.setShowGrid(false);` ..? (Then you'd need to 'fake' borders as needed in the renderer)

Comment: umm... I mean, Hide the 'value' in the cell, not hide a 'line' on the table...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And, I don't know how DefaultTableCellRenderer works. Can't find any explains about that...

Maybe start with the Swing tutorial on [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

You can't use an instance variable to track the previous value because you can't be guaranteed that the rows will always be rendered in sequential order. For example if row 1 is selected and then you click on row 10, only rows 1 and 10 will be repainted.

So the solution is to compare the previous value in the render with code something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JTable table = new JTable(10, 1);
        table.setValueAt("one", 0, 0);
        table.setValueAt("one", 1, 0);
        table.setValueAt("two", 2, 0);
        table.setValueAt("two", 3, 0);
        table.setValueAt("two", 4, 0);
        table.setValueAt("three", 5, 0);
        add( new JScrollPane( table ) );

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer( new DuplicateRenderer() );
    }

    /*
    **  Color the focused cell
    */
    class DuplicateRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
    {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
        {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            if (row > 0 && value != null)
            {
                Object previous = table.getValueAt(row - 1, column);

                if (value.equals(previous))
                {
                    setText("");
                }
            }

            return this;
        }
    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```